# Convert an UnsafePointer (#dsohandle) to String

Tags: swift

I want to convert #dsohandle to String to have a precise identifier for my App instance.

I've tried to convert the

> UnsafeRawPointer

to Data, and using the initializer for String in order to do so but in both cases I do not seem able to convert it.

Any ideas?

Comment: #dsohandle is an *address* (a pointer), what kind of string  would you expect? And what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: A precise identifier for my App instance. A String description of it, in a similar way to #file gives the filename

Comment: The pointer is only meaningful in the address space of the process, and every process has its own address space. If multiple instances of your app run simultaneously then each one can have the same value for #dsoHandle.

Comment: You can get a string with `String(Int(bitPattern: #dsohandle))`, but most probably, that will be the same for all apps.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the `dladdr` function. There is no online documentation for it, but macOS comes with a manual page for it, which you can access using the `man dladdr` command in the terminal. Among other things, it can give you *"The pathname of the shared object containing the address."*, which sounds like the closest thing to a unique identifier for an arbitrary executable that might not have a bundle identifier.

```swift
import Darwin

func getPathFromDynamicObjectHandle(_ dynamicObjectHandle: UnsafeRawPointer = #dsohandle) -> String? {
    var info = Dl_info()
    guard dladdr(dynamicObjectHandle, &info) != 0 else {
        return nil
    }
    return String(cString: info.dli_fname)
```